# Expectation of minimum growth

Tags: probability, expected-value

Suppose $\mathbb E[X] \geq n$, is it true that:
$$\mathbb E[\min\{n, X\}] \geq n \cdot a$$
for some constant $a>0$?

Answer (score 0):

Pick $X$ such that with probability $\frac1{n+2}$, $X=(n+1)(n+2) +1$ and $X=-1$ otherwise.

This is a counterexample when $n>0$.

Comment: Is there a counterexample when $X \geq 0$?

Comment: For any given $a$, let $0<p<1$ and $p<a$. Then let $X = \frac np$ with probability $p$ and $0$ otherwise